# Retrofit onResponse not error even operation occured

Tags: android, retrofit2

Even though every thing is working properly and registration is happening. Retrofit on Response don't get called but onFailure gets called. Call.isexecutted returns true.
I am showing the model class and registrationFragment where the error occured. This is taking a lot time. So thanks in advance for help

**RegistrationFragment.java**

```
    package com.example.milan.hospital;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class RegistrationFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText Name,UserName, UserPassword;
    private Button BnRegister;



    public RegistrationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration, container, false);

        Name = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        UserName = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_name);
        UserPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        BnRegister = view.findViewById(R.id.bn_register);

        BnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                performRegistration();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void performRegistration()
    {
        String name = Name.getText().toString();
        String username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();

        Call<User> call = MainActivity.apiInterface.performRegistration(name,username,password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {


                if(response.body().getResponse().equals("ok"))
                {
                    MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("Registration success...");
                }
                else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("exist"))
                {
                    MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("User already exist....");
                }
                else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("error"))
                {
                    MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("Something went wrong...");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });


        Name.setText("");
        UserPassword.setText("");
        UserName.setText("");

    }

}
```

**User.java**

```
    package com.example.milan.hospital;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

    @SerializedName("response")
    private String Response;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String Name;

    public String getResponse() {
        return Response;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.milan.hospital;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginFragment.OnLoginFormActivityListener{

    public static PrefConfig prefConfig;
    public static ApiInterface apiInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefConfig = new PrefConfig(this);
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null)
        {
            if(savedInstanceState != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if(prefConfig.readLoginStatus())
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new WelcomeFragment()).commit();
            }
            else
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new LoginFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void performRegister() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new RegistrationFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void performLogin(String name) {

    }
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
    package com.example.milan.hospital;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiInterface
{
    @GET("register.php")
    Call<User> performRegistration(@Query("name") String Name,@Query("user_name") String UserName,@Query("user_password") String UserPassword);

    @GET("login.php")
    Call<User> performUserLogin(@Query("user_name") String UserName,@Query("user_password") String UserPassword);
}
```

Comment: If you can add json response comming from server, will be more helpful.

Comment: Logcat output: retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@240238

Comment: at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1352)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)

Comment: Your JSON seems to be invalid. Please use the edit button for providing more details. Comments are difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the ApiClient to this. As there was a well known problem of  retrofit while reading json. to resolve we have initialize gson object ourself

```
public class ApiClient
{
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.3.2/loginapp/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        if(retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();


        }
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think performRegistration() in ApiInterface.java should have an annotation of @POST rather than @GET since registration is the act of posting data rather than getting. Give it a try once.

Comment: try replacing Query with Field annotation in ApiInterface.java

Comment: retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@240238 output of logcat

Comment: at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1352)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)